# C++: Reading in one character at a time until the end of a line not working

Tags: c++, char

I'm supposed to read a text file one character at a time and every time there is a new line the `line` should be increased by one.

So here is the relevant part of code:

```
ifstream textFile.open("PATHWAY::HERE//RRER.txt");
int line = 1;
char letter;
while (textFile)
{
  //Read in letter
  textFile >> letter;

  // If you reach the end of the line
  if (letter == '\n')
  {
    line++;
    cout << line;
  }
}
```

The if statement is completely ignored for some reason and doesn't ever print out line.

Comment: Newline is `\n` with a backslash, not `/n`

Comment: The `>>` operator will skip over white space anyways and read "word" by "word".

Comment: plus, line should be line = 0;

Comment: Use textFile.get instead of textFile >>.

Comment: My mistake - I mistyped when I typed it on here. It still doesn't do anything. In fact if I put a `cout << line;` inside the if statement after line++; it doesn't even do the if statement at all

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ - Getting a single character. Extraction and insertion operators operate on words (delimited by whitespace).

Comment: Your loop is wrong, you should be doing `while (textFile >> letter)`. Right now you won't notice errors or end of file until too late. The reason is that the error/eof flags aren't set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file (for eof).

Comment: @ZDF thank you sir that worked

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for the heads up, will change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the answers (till now) have mentioned the problem about "\n" correctly, the approach mentioned may not work. Reason being `>>` is formatted input operator which will skip whitespaces. You  will have to read the file using `std::ifstream::get`

The code will look something like:

```
while (textfile.get(letter))
{
            // If you reach the end of the line
    if (letter == '\n')
    {
        line++;
        cout << line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code:

- it's '\n' not '/n'
- line = 0 not 1
- you need to use `std::ifstream::get` to read the file
- delete `textFile>> letter;` because it will skip the `whitespaces`

So your code will be like the following

```
ifstream textFile.open("PATHWAY::HERE//RRER.txt");
        int line = 0; // not 1
        char letter;
        while(textFile.get(letter))
            {
             // If you reach the end of the line
                if (letter == '\n')
                {
                    line++;
                    cout << line;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find whether that is new line or not by using `\n` character

so your code should be

```
ifstream textFile.open("PATHWAY::HERE//RRER.txt");
  int line = 1;
   char letter;
  while (textFile)
    {
    // Read in letter
    textFile>> letter;

    // If you reach the end of the line
    if (letter == '\n')
    {
        line++;
        cout << line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `istream::get`

```
ifstream textFile.open("PATHWAY::HERE//RRER.txt");
int line = 0;
char letter;
while(textFile.get(letter))
{
  // If you reach the end of the line
  if (letter == '/n')
  {
    line++;
    cout << line;
  }
}
```